# Sass color variable not working inside darken()

Tags: sass

I've got list of colors and I would like to use darken() on them like so:

```
$innerPagesBgColors: "#6B46C1", "#2980B9", "#FD5456", "#000";

.foo {
    color: darken(nth($innerPagesBgColors, 3), 5%);
}
```

But I get this error:

> $color: "#FD5456" is not a color for `darken'

I tried interpolating the nth() portion but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that darken function requires a color as first argument and, instead, you're trying to pass a string.

```
type-of(#6B46C1); // returns color
type-of("#6B46C1"); // returns string
```

So you should remove all quotes in `$innerPagesBgColors`:

```
$innerPagesBgColors: #6B46C1, #2980B9, #FD5456, #000;
```

Comment: I have a related issue where I am forced to have a string for my color. Do you have an answer to that? I might create a question soon.

Comment: You can remove the quotes using the `unquote()` function. http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/string#unquote

Answer (score 2):

In my case I solved with this.

```
@each $name, $color in $set_colors{
  // check type-of before
  @if (type-of($color) == 'color'){
    .color-#{$name}{
      color: #{$color};
    }

    .background-#{$name}{
      background-color: $color;

      &:hover{
        background-color: darken($color, 10%);
      }
    }
  }
}
```