# SASS mixin if second paramater is undefined use first paramater instead

Tags: css, sass

This piece of code won't work :

```
@mixin something($param1, $param2:$param1) {
    background-color: $param2
}
body {
    @include something('black');
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Code compiles as expected.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535869/sass-color-variable-not-working-inside-darken

Comment: just remove the quotes and everything works