# Sass lighten function output in rgb

Tags: colors, sass, mixins

I have a set of sass config variables:

```
$color-primary:     (68, 26, 103);   
$color-seconday:    (0, 153, 160);   
$color-tertiary:    (172, 165, 22);  
$color-black:       (0, 0 ,0 );      
$color-white:       (255, 255 ,255); 
$color-link:        (0, 133, 178);
```

I have a `@mixin` to take the colors and output rgba (if set) and rgb fallback:

```
@mixin rgba($property, $color, $opacity: 1) {
  $rgb-start: "rgb(";
  $rgba-start: "rgba(";
  $color-end: ")";

  #{$property}: #{$rgb-start} $color #{$color-end};

  @if $opacity != 1 {
    #{$property}: #{$rgba-start} $color, $opacity #{$color-end};
  }
}
```

The problem is i've got a few other variables that make use of sass' `lighten` function which then outputs the color in hex and not particularly useful with my new `@mixin rgba`.

```
$color-grey-100:    rgb(0, 0, 0);
$color-grey-80:     lighten($color-grey-100, 20%);
$color-grey-60:     lighten($color-grey-100, 40%);
$color-grey-40:     lighten($color-grey-100, 60%);
$color-grey-20:     lighten($color-grey-100, 80%);
```

I'm merely looking for a few suggestions as you I don't think you can change the output of the lighten function.

Comment: Why is this a problem?  Sass always outputs colors in the shortest format, which is hex.

Comment: Because my rgba mixin takes rgb colours therefore it outputs `color: rgb#ccc;`

Comment: That does not answer my question.  If you just used a color to begin with instead of a string containing what looks like a color, you could pass it to any of the color functions.  Now why is it so important that it is rgb instead of hex?

Comment: I have read your question.  You prefer to use rgb for convenience when declaring the variable, fine.  I am asking **why it has to be rgb for the output**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SASS color variable not working inside darken()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535869/sass-color-variable-not-working-inside-darken)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757665/sass-color-variable-hex-output

Comment: It has to be rgb for the output because you can't have transparency with a hex code, unlike rgba( ), and I've got rgb( ) in there as a backup for devices/browsers that don't support rgba( )

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that partially transparent colors have a solid fallback for browsers that lack rgba support, you just need to manipulate the transparency.

```
@mixin graceful-color($prop, $color) {
  @if alpha($color) < 1 {
    #{$prop}: opacify($color, 1);
  }
  #{$prop}: $color;
}

.foo {
  @include graceful-color(color, rgb(255, 255, 255));
  @include graceful-color(background, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5));
}
```

Output:

```
.foo {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```