# Error: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color

Tags: sass

I have the same problem as this question: [Sass color variable not working inside darken()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535869/sass-color-variable-not-working-inside-darken)

But the difference between me and this question's poster is that I use the color already as color (not as string).

My code looks like this:

```
body {
  @each $name, $num, $color in ('ClassName1', '01', #f39c12) ('ClassName2', '02', ) {
    &.#{$name} {
      background-color: darken($color, 10%);
      background-image: url('img/bg-#{$num}');
    }
  }
}
```

Of course I already removed the unnecessary stuff. I am still getting this error:

```
Error: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
```

I got the same problem with rgba:

```
Error: argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color
```

Edit.: Now i see that i get this problem not because anything is wrong with my code... i just forgot to place any color in the second array... `@each $name, $num, $color in ('ClassName1', '01', #f39c12) ('ClassName2', '02', #FORGOT-THIS)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your @each? Can you give some more content or a demo?

Comment: I found the reason for my problem and edit my post.

Answer (score -3):

Install 4.0.0-alpha.6 version of bootstrap. it should fix the issue.

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

You would be using 4.0.0+ version of bootstrap

I have used it and it worked for me , please share your error details if still not works for you. :)